# Call js-function using JQuery timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to implement a timer for JQuery, eg. every 10 seconds it needs to call a js function.

I tried the following

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
 alert('test');
}, 10000);
```

but this only executes once and then never again.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can use this:

```
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000);

function yourfunction() { alert('test'); }
```

Answer (score 50):

```
window.setInterval(function() {
 alert('test');
}, 10000);
```

**[window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)**

> Calls a function repeatedly, with a
>   fixed time delay between each call to
>   that function.

Answer (score 45):

Might want to check out **jQuery Timer** to manage one or multiple timers.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

```
var timer = $.timer(yourfunction, 10000);

function yourfunction() { alert('test'); }
```

Then you can control it with:

```
timer.play();
timer.pause();
timer.toggle();
timer.once();
etc...
```

Comment: nice utility. Allows controlling lifecycle.

Comment: very useful for when one timer needs to control another timer

Comment: i m getting an error :( "TypeError: $.timer is not a function"

Comment: that is because you need to get the plugin from the link.

Answer (score 25):

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is the function you want. That repeats every x miliseconds.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    alert('test');
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 11):

jQuery 1.4 also includes a .delay( duration, [ queueName ] ) method if you only need it to trigger once and have already started using that version.

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Ooops....my mistake you were looking for an event to continue triggering. I'll leave this here, someone may find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

try jQueryTimers, they have great functionality for polling

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **setInterval()** method also you can call your **setTimeout()**
from your custom function for example

```
function everyTenSec(){
  console.log("done");
  setTimeout(everyTenSec,10000);
}
everyTenSec();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function run() {
    window.setTimeout(
         "run()",
         1000
    );
}
```

Comment: -1, because providing a string to eval instead of simply providing the function is the root of too many bugs.