# Ajax script that checks the contents of the file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need Ajax script that will check every 5 seconds, the contents of file.php

file.php may contain only `true` or `false`.

If true - script must perform an action.
if false - script should continue to check the file for true

how to make it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: @pekka I know, but I need this assistance, which inspire my mind to create a code that I need.

Comment: What inspiration do you need exactly, can you specify the point at which you get stuck? Which of the tasks are you having trouble with?

Comment: @user1062240 : you have to listen to the above comments and please put watever code u have done right now..

Comment: @Pekka I do not understand how to make the script scan file.php ever 5 sec..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will this help?

[Call js-function using JQuery timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295049/jquery-timer-how-do-i-do-this)

then use jquery ajax methods.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I would help you more but you need to first help your self.

Comment: If you have any problems post your code explaining whats not working and what you have tried. We will be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

For a starting point ave a look at this -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Example: Gets the test.php page contents, which has been returned in json format (`<?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); ?>`), and adds it to the page.

```
 $.get("test.php",
   function(data){
     $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
              .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
   }, "json");
```

To repeat something every # seconds have a look at the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function :

> Calls a function repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call
>   to that function.

Then when you have created some code - come back and post your issues

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform regular [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call inside [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/). Maybe [clearInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) would be useful too, if you want to stop checking remote file.