# I need example of text animation dynamically added to a Div?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I want to make an text animation with JQuery but I dont know how should i start and how should i code this. Actually what/where to google it.

**If you look at http://www.apple.com/stevejobs/ you see that text are moving and the last is added to the top with nice fadeout and so on.
Could you help me to give an example/ scratch of doing it in JQuery Ajax and html.**

I want to implement it in Python as backend and in the front use Ajax ,JQuery, Javascript and so on. please give hint that which one is better.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1. Put text in `<div>`s
2. Use [jQuery's effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) to show, hide, and animate the text.
3. Optionally add [jQuery UI's easing effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) and use something like the `easeInOutCubic` easing function.

Comment: Can you refer me a site that has example ?

Comment: little bit new in these stuff

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time, but check out the second link in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started atleast with the effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div { background:#de9a44; margin:3px; width:80px; 
height:40px;  }
#one { background:#de9a44; margin:3px; width:80px; 
height:40px; display:none;  }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<script>
    //sets a timer to 1sec
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(yourfunction, 1000);
});

    //goes to a php file and return data to be appended to your div.
function yourfunction() {   
    $.get("test.php", function(data){
        $("#one").html(data)
        $("#one").slideDown("slow");

    });

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

timer thanks to [Kristof Claes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295049/jquery-timer-how-do-i-do-this) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) more info on the jquery get() function.  My recommendation for you is to map out a logic of what you want to accomplish, and search for how it might be called and start forming piece by piece your result..That's what I do, I'm no expert in jquery but i have an idea and thanks to great people in in S.O. and google I am able to accomplish awesome things.

Comment: Can you describe it with little text,  how should i fill the one with data, which data model is better ? and how it works ?