# jquery drop down menu with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, navigation

I want to make html/jquery drop down menu. But I have a problem. I want that when mouse goes to "games" navigation button, div came down and only disappeared when the mouse is out FOR 5 seconds, not AFTER 5 seconds (this is my problem), not instantly. Here it is what I have done, so far

JS

```
    var games_timer = $.timer(slidingUP("#games-sub", "-200px")); games_timer.set({ time : 3000, autostart : false });

    function slidingUP($name, $value){
        $($name).animate({ top : $value }, 300);
        }

    $(".games").hover(function(){
            if (games_timer.active){games_timer.stop();}
            $("#games-sub").animate({ top : "160px" }, 300);

        }, function(){
            games_timer.play();
        });
```

It slides down, but never slides up

Html:

```
<ul>
 <li class="nav-a1"><a id="home" href="">Home</a></li>
 <li class="nav-a2"><a id="games" class="games" href="">Games</a></li>
 <li class="nav-a2"><a id="upcomming" href="">Upcomming</a></li>
 <li class="nav-a2"><a id="trailers" href="">Trailers</a></li>
 <li class="nav-a2"><a id="blog" href="">Blog</a></li>
 <li class="nav-a2"><a id="login" href="">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="games-sub" class="games">
    <a href="">ACTION</a>
    <a href="">ADVANTURE</a>
    <a href="">ARCADE</a>
    <a href="">SHOOTER</a>
    <a href="">FIRST PERSON</a>
    <a href="">THIRD PERSON</a>
    <a href="">STRATEGY</a>
    <a href="">SPORT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`? Plus, you could add your code on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dP78/) with some css. It will be easier for us to help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295049/jquery-timer-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: 300 here is not a timeout - it is animation duration

Answer (score 0):

you can hook up to the `mousein` and `mouseout` events of the div.
on `mouseout`, you would start a `timeout` event that would close the div in 5 seconds.
on `mousein` you would check if a timeout event for closing the div exists. if so- cancel it. if not- show the div.
[here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)'s some explanation concerning timeout events.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
    $('.games').hover(function() {
        timeout = setTimeout('showSubGames()', 1000);
    });

function showSubGames()
{
 $("#games-sub").animate({ top : "160px" }, 300);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered my question, but here is what i have done, and it doesn't works:



  var games_timer = $.timer(slideUP("#games-sub", "-200px")); timer.set({ time : 3000, autostart : false });
  
  function slideUP($name, $value){
   $($name).animate({ top : $value }, 300);
   }
  
  $(".games").hover(function(){
    if (games_timer.active){games_timer.stop();}
    $("#games-sub").animate({ top : "160px" }, 300);
    
   }, function(){
    games_timer.play();
   });
  

can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: firstly, slideUp is a predefined function in jquery so i advise you to change its name unless you are trying to override it. and please try to mark the code like this `code` so as to clarify it

Comment: `var games_timer = $.timer(slidingUP("#games-sub", "-200px")); timer.set({ time : 3000, autostart : false });
  
  function slidingUP($name, $value){
   $($name).animate({ top : $value }, 300);
   }
  
  $(".games").hover(function(){
    if (games_timer.active){games_timer.stop();}
    $("#games-sub").animate({ top : "160px" }, 300);
    
   }, function(){
    games_timer.play();
   });`

Comment: did you try to change the name of slideUp function?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you want to delay the slidingUp function 5 seconds; therefore, your solution is to use the .delay like the following:

```
function slidingUP($name, $value){
    $($name).animate({ top : $value }, 300).delay(300);
   }
```

Comment: ok can you repeat your question here again, what do you want to happen on hover and onmouse out

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an event on mouseleave

```
$(".games").mouseleave(function(){

        $("#games-sub").animate({ top : "-200px" }, 300).delay(300);

    }
```

or without the delay:

```
$(".games").mouseleave(function(){

        $("#games-sub").animate({ top : "-200px" }, 300);

    }
```

Comment: ok, I know that it is an easy answer, but you must mention that when mouse goes From "games" to sub menu, this sub menu will go up and down for few times, that's why I want to use the time, I want that sub menu went up when mouse will be out FOR 3 seconds, NOT AFTER 3 seconds, did you get it?

Comment: I can suggest a whole new approach to do your menu if you want. because i dont think its correct to assume that the user will click in 3 seconds

Comment: coooome ooonn dude, you just don't want to understand me, I didn't say that user will click something in 3 seconds... I give up, is anybody here who can really understand me?