# extend the session with user prompt

Tags: java, javascript

In web xml the session time out is set to 10 minitus as below,

```
<session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
```

I want to promote a message box for user after 8 minits when user is idel asking user to extend the session and if user click on ok, then extend the session by another 10 minits.

How could i achive this using java script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16034362/2857356 go through this link It may help you to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You could perform an ajax call to the server. That should reset the session timer to 10 minutes. Make some no-op method and call that with ajax.

Or it doesn't necessarily need to be ajax either. But you'll need to communicate with the server somehow (such as submitting a form or reloading the page).

Comment: In the case of ajax call, i need to reset the session time out value in the HttpSession object know?

Comment: session-timeout value is define is web.xml. So in this case how could i read it from java script, so i can keep track of when user idle for 2 minits before session-timeout value  and prompt the dialogue.

Comment: You can start a javascript timer on the page whenever it's loaded, that counts down from 10 minutes, then show the message. And you don't need to do anything to the HttpSession object, it's transparent to you.