# Jquery ajax post with timer event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var meter_id = $("#MeterReadingTypes li a.link_active").attr("id");
    var range_id = $("#DateRangeTypes li a.link_active").attr("id");

    window.setInterval(PostMainChartValues(meter_id, range_id), 5000);
    ...
});

function PostMainChartValues(meter_id, range_type_id) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

window.setInterval is not trigerred. If I write an alert in setInterval it works. What is the reason of this? Why function is not triggering? I tracked it with chrome DevTools, and there is no move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter to `setInterval` should be a **function** (or an `eval`able string). Right now, you are calling `PostMainChartValues()` and passing its return value to `setInterval()`.

Change it to:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    PostMainChartValues(meter_id, range_id);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Or SO's websockets notified me a few milliseconds earlier. :) Unlikely that I'm faster. :-)

Comment: It works, but I cant understand fully. What is the difference with [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295049/call-js-function-using-jquery-timer)

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: In your example you're assigning the _returned value_ not the function it self as `setInterval` expects.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ajax issue. You are using in wrong mode the `setInterval` parameter.

Create an anonymous `function` like bellow:

```
window.setInterval(function () { PostMainChartValues(meter_id, range_id); }, 5000);
```